# Undo git merge to remote branch

Tags: git

So long story short I had a remote branch I was working on (my-remote-branch) that was failing some tests in the CI. I was told to rebase to master to fix this issue.

I did the following:

```
git checkout master
git pull
git checkout my-remote-branch
git rebase master
git push
```

At that point I got an error:

```
 hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
 hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
 hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
```

So next I did:

```
 git pull --set-upstream-origin my-remote-branch
 git push
```

This kind of just created a mess. My pull request now has a massive amount of commits (all the ones from master) so the history is all messed up and there's a misleading number of changed files for the pull request. This seems more complicated than a simple revert since I can't just revert back to one commit, all the commits are intertwined from master.

Apparently what I was **supposed** to do was this:

```
 git fetch origin master
 git rebase -I origin/master
 git push —force
```

Is there a way I can undo my mistake (undo the merge, remove commits from history in my branch only) so I can execute the step I was supposed to do?

Comment: `--set-upstream-origin` is not an option to `git pull`. `--set-upstream`, without the `-origin` part, *is* an option to `git push`. The `-force` should be `--force` (Git is picky about number of dashes) and `-I` should be `-i` (Git is picky about upper vs lower case, too). The last two are probably just typos, but I don't want to guess which commands above have simple typos and which have more serious oddities going on, so it would be helpful if you got those straightened out in your question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can undo the last commit with

```sh
git checkout my-remote-branch
git reset --hard HEAD~1
```

[source](https://www.git-tower.com/learn/git/faq/undo-last-commit)

if the last commit wasn't the "bad" one, then you can use `git log` to find the last hash of the last good commit an then do

```sh
git reset --hard HASH
```

(replace `HASH` with the repective hash).

---

after that you are back where you started and can do what you think would have been correct.